# ArraysList as JSON

Tags: java, json, arraylist, hashmap

I wrote the below code in order for me to output a `ArrayList` as JSON. When I ran the code I get the output as shown below:

> {uniteids:=[{"UniteId:":"gsheetyr","Message:":" The given user is already a member of the given DL.,"},{"UniteId:":"spokuri ","Message:":" The given user is already a member of the given DL.,"}]}

But, I wanted the output to be in the below format. Can you please let me know what changes I need to make to my code?

> {"uniteids":[{"UniteId:":"gsheetyr","Message:":" The given user is already a member of the given DL.,"},{"UniteId:":"spokuri ","Message:":" The given user is already a member of the given DL.,"}]}

Code:

```
package com.uniteid.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;

public class JsonResponse {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> retStatus = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, String> stat = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String jsonInString = "NORESPONSE";
    String jsonInString2 = "";
    Map<String, String> uniteidshashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    retStatus.add("gsheetyr: The given user is already a member of the given DL.,");
    retStatus.add("spokuri : The given user is already a member of the given DL.,");

    if (retStatus.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < retStatus.size(); i++) {
            String splited[] = retStatus.get(i).split("\\:");

            stat.put("UniteId:", splited[0]);
            stat.put("Message:",splited[1]);
            ja.put(stat);   

            System.out.println(ja);
        }

        jsonInString = ja.toString();
        uniteidshashMap.put("uniteids:", jsonInString);
        jsonInString2 = uniteidshashMap.toString();

        System.out.println(jsonInString2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Edwin Looks like it is php, I am writing in java

Comment: Calling toString() on a java map will add the "=" sign. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#toString()

Comment: @sarathmandava oh sorry :D mixed up posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
JSONArray arrayHolder = new JSONArray();
if (retStatus.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < retStatus.size(); i++) {
        String splited[] = retStatus.get(i).split("\\:");

        JSONObject innerObj = new JSONObject();

        innerObj.put("UniteId:", splited[0]);
        innerObj.put("Message:",splited[1]);
        arrayHolder.put(innerObj);   
    }

    JSONObject finalObject = new JSONObject();
    finalObject.put("uniteids:", arrayHolder);

    System.out.println(finalObject.toString());
}
```

Comment: Tried it I got the below output. I don't want \ in the output   {
  "uniteids:": "[{\"UniteId:\":\"gsheetyr\",\"Message:\":\"The given user is already a member of the given DL.\"},{\"UniteId:\":\"spokuri\",\"Message:\":\"The given user is already a member of the given DL.\"},{\"UniteId:\":\"test\",\"Message:\":\"Exception occured--20108-ORA-20108\"},{\"UniteId:\":\"desa-icts-support@unhqtest.un.org\",\"Message:\":\"The given group is already a member of the given DL.\"},{\"UniteId:\":\"ram@un.org\",\"Message:\":\" The given callerid / DL email is not valid.\"}]"
}

Comment: Aaah!! got you. we are getting a singe json string the value. I'll modify my answer to get a proper JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you wrap your `uniteidshashMap` object inside a `JsonArray` and call `toString()` on that instead, you'll get a better result.